# Setting server buffer size on glassfish

Tags: websocket, server, glassfish, buffer

I want to transfer up to 16MB large files through websockets. When I try to send a file greater than 3MB it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: Unexpected error, closing connection.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer overflow.
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.Utils.appendBuffers(Utils.java:346)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine$TyrusReadHandler.handle(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:523)
```

I have read that buffer size can be changed inside glassfish-web.xml file by adding:

```
<param-name>org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.incoming-buffer-size</param-name>
<param-value>17000000</param-value>
```

into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/PROJECT</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

but it didn't work out for me. Is there any other option or am I doing something wrong.